# Having trouble getting form data with PHP

Tags: php

Hey all from what I can tell my code looks like it should work but it's not. I am not seeing where my error is. When I fill out the form and press submit I am able to get the first variable for name, but phone and email do not show up. Can someone point out where my error(s) are?
    `
    
    Form Test

```
<body>

<form action="clientData.php" method="post">
What is your name?
<input type="text" name="name">

<br>
What is your email address?
<input type ="text" email="email">

<br>
What is your phone number?
<input type = "text" phone="phone">
</br>
<input type="submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

And here is my clientData.php file where I want to store my variables to insert into my database.

`<?php
    $clientName= $_POST['name'];
    $clientEmail= $_POST['email'];
    echo $clientName;
    echo $clientEmail;
    ?>`

Comment: Yep it was the name tag. Can't believe I overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your form like this :

```
<form action="clientData.php" method="post">
What is your name?
<input type="text" name="name">

<br>
What is your email address?
<input type="text" name="email">

<br>
What is your phone number?
<input type="text" name="phone">
</br>
<input type="submit">
```

And the PHP :

```
<?php
$clientName= $_POST['name'];
$clientEmail= $_POST['email'];
$clientPhone= $_POST['phone'];
?>
```

The `HTML` attribute which define the index of the value in the `POST` array is `name`, so for example to create a field, you need to do it like this :

```
<input type="text" name="theNameOfTheField">
```

And to get the result in PHP :

```
<?php
$fieldValue= $_POST['theNameOfTheField'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type ="text" name="email" id="name">
```

If you dont name the element, its not gona work.

Answer (score 1):

```
What is your email address?
<input type ="text" email="email">

<br>
What is your phone number?
<input type = "text" phone="phone">
```

The error here is that the input name should be name and not the field name

```
What is your email address?
<input type ="text" name="email">

<br>
What is your phone number?
<input type = "text" name="phone">
```